# How to play vimeo videos within my app?

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-android

I want to play vimeo videos in my application. I am able to get the Videos from the channel and play in the browser or in the vimeo application, but i want the video to be played in my application. Is there any API for this like open youtube. Please help me in doing this.

for now i am using this to play video in the vimeo app or in the browser.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+vid_id)));
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this? i want to play vimeo video in webiew but all it is showing is white screen

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all you need is a webview.

Url would be something like:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/<VIDEO_ID_GOES_HERE>?player_id=player&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1&api=1
```

Edit: Vimeo offers a html5 player, see here: http://vimeo.com/blog/post:268
this way you should be able to read the filename and play this in your application.

Edit 2: html5 is not available anylonger .

Comment: looks like this function is deacticvated by vimeo. well then you can also download the flv files and play them

Comment: i have to get videos from channels and play them. I think it's not possible to download flv and play..

Answer (score 0):

The alternative option is to get a Pro account and then you can load the videos directly in the native player.

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29498705/958651

APIs for Vimeo are found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api and here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints